# How to use loop to create obj in javascript

Tags: javascript

My aim is to create something like this

```
  $rootScope.customMarkers = [
          {address: "1600 pennsylvania ave, washington DC", "class": "my1"},
          {address: "600 pennsylvania ave, washington DC",  "class": "my2"},
  ];
```

Here is part of my code, yet this does not work

```
  for (var i = 0; i < cart.length; i++) {
    $rootScope.customMarkers = [{
        address: cart[i].address,
        "class": cart[i].class,
    }];
  }
```

Could anyone give me some clues or just give me some key words?

Comment: please add `cart` as well.

Comment: The problem is everytime you go round your loop you're setting `$rootScope.cusomMarkers` to a new array with only one object, I suggest you have a look at [push()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push?v=control)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code will not work since you have to [push](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push?v=control) objects to array:

```
$rootScope.customMarkers = [];

for (var i = 0; i < cart.length; i++) {
    $rootScope.customMarkers.push({
        address: cart[i].address,
        "class": cart[i].class,
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 4):

Your current code *overwrites* `$rootscope.customMarkers` on each loop iteration with a new array containing just one entry.

This is a classic use of [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map?v=control):

```
$rootScope.customMarkers = cart.map(function(entry) {
    return {address: entry.address, class: entry.class};
});
```

...assuming `cart` is an array. If it isn't, it's just array-like, you might use [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from):

```
$rootScope.customMarkers = Array.from(cart, function(entry) {
    return {address: entry.address, class: entry.class};
});
```

...or a boring old loop:

```
$rootScope.customMarkers = [];
for (var i = 0; i < cart.length; ++i) {
    $rootScope.customMarkers[i] = {address: cart[i].address, class: cart[i].class};
}
```

---

Side note: As of ES5, both uses of `class` above are valid, you don't have to put quotes around one but not the other. If you need to handle old engines that may not handle it, you need to handle it in both places: `"class": entry["class"]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use foreach loop for angularjs

```
angular.forEach(cart, function(value, key) {
    $rootScope.customMarkers.push({
        address : value.address,
        class : value.class
    });
});
```

It's done.

Comment: ...perhaps starting with `$rootScope.customMarkers = [];`.

Comment: Yes, need to define a blank object above foreach loop.